# prompt function does not accept input which only contains numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, integer, prompt

I have added confirmation dialog to input again the status I get before submitting.

That park works.
Problem is that `prompt()` function does not except inputing just numbers?

Is there anyway I can added that part to so it can pass?

```
$(".delete-status").click(function (ev, el) {

    var status = $(this).data("status");
    var statusInput = prompt("Confirm deletion by entering the status:");

    if (statusInput === status) {

        statusDelete(status);
    } else if (statusInput === null || statusInput === "") {

        alert("Field should not be empty!");
    } else {

        alert("Entered status and status don't match!");
    }
});
```

Any idea how to fix the code? I am pretty new at jQuery and JS. Thanks

I want to  cover both cases. With string and with number.

Comment: `prompt()` returns a string. `status` is an integer. Since you use strict equality, they don't match.

Comment: You put a check against what the user has entered and loop around until they enter valid data (need some way to exit though).   Or, use a different component such as a modal dialog or 3rd-party "prompt" component.   `prompt()` will always be text input without validation, it's only meant as a basic UI component for simple sites / proof-of-concept.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `.data()` method automatically parses the data as JSON if it can, so if it looks numeric it will return a number, not a string.

`prompt()` always returns a string (or `null` if you cancel).

So you need to convert `status` and `statusInput` to the same type if you want to compare them with `===`. You can use `parseInt()` to convert the user input to an integer.

```js
$(".delete-status").click(function(ev, el) {

  var status = $(this).data("status");
  var statusInput = parseInt(prompt("Confirm deletion by entering the status:"));

  if (statusInput === status) {

    statusDelete(status);
  } else if (statusInput === null || statusInput === "") {

    alert("Field should not be empty!");
  } else {

    alert("Entered status and status don't match!");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for replay. If I use parseInt in all cases will it affect if the status is just string? @Barmar

Comment: You should only use it if you expect the user to enter a number.

Comment: The alternative is to convert `status` to a string: `$(this).data("status").toString()`

Comment: If `$(this).data("status")` *is* a string, then parseInt() on the prompt will not match

Comment: Other alternatives:  `if (statusInput == status)`  (though generally people recommend `===` as `==` can cause errors if you don't know what you're doing) (despite the evidence that "===" seems to cause more errors...)

Comment: Other alternatives: `if (statusInput === status || parseInt(statusInput) === status)`  move the parseInt to the `if` (take it off the `prompt`)

Comment: But as you're using `===` and not `<` vs `>`, probably easiest to ensure `status` is a string as above or other method to convert to string such as  `$(this).data("status") + ""`

Answer (score 0):

You could convert `statusInput` string to a number.

This could be better but something along the lines of:

```
$(".delete-status").click(function (ev, el) {
    var status = $(this).data("status");
    var statusInput = prompt("Confirm deletion by entering the status:");

    if (Number(statusInput) === Number(status)) {
        statusDelete(status);
    } else if (statusInput === null || statusInput === "") {
        alert("Field should not be empty!");
    } else {
        alert("Entered status and status don't match!");
    }
})
```

Comment: Yes but I think it will be problem as I want to  cover both cases. With string and with number.. @MikeW